# Есть заголовок с ротацией фраз. Сейчас фразы сменяют друг друга с эффектом затухания, а нужно чтоб менялись с эффектом слайда снизу вверх

Tags: javascript

```js
var slides = document.querySelectorAll('#slides .slide');
var currentSlide = 0;
var slideInterval = setInterval(nextSlide, 3000);

function nextSlide() {
  slides[currentSlide].className = 'slide';
  currentSlide = (currentSlide + 1) % slides.length;
  slides[currentSlide].className = 'slide showing';
}
```

```css
#slides {
  position: relative;
  height: 70px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 20px;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.slide {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: opacity 1s;
}

.showing {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 2;
}

.slide {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Montserrat";
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 62px;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /*color: #ffffff;*/
}
```

```html
<ul id="slides">
  <li class="slide"> Управляйте производством</li>
  <li class="slide showing"> Контролируйте процессы</li>
  <li class="slide"> Повышайте эффективность</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

В простейшем виде так - спозиционировали на 100%, а при добавлении класса вернули на 0, а так же скорректировали `transition: top 1s`. И обязательно добавить `overflow:hidden`, чтобы не было видно на крайней позиции. `opacity` чтобы при уходе прошлого элемента он не портил картину

```js
var slides = document.querySelectorAll('#slides .slide');
var currentSlide = 0;
var slideInterval = setInterval(nextSlide, 3000);

function nextSlide() {
  slides[currentSlide].className = 'slide';
  currentSlide = (currentSlide + 1) % slides.length;
  slides[currentSlide].className = 'slide showing';
}
```

```css
#slides {
  position: relative;
  height: 70px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 20px;
  list-style-type: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slide {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: top 1s;
  top: 100%;
}

.showing {
  top: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: top 1s, opacity 0s;
  z-index: 2;
}

.slide {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Montserrat";
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 32px;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<ul id="slides">
  <li class="slide"> Управляйте производством</li>
  <li class="slide showing"> Контролируйте процессы</li>
  <li class="slide"> Повышайте эффективность</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!!!